# How to re.match or re.search numbers in Python

Tags: python

I want to match exact double digit numbers after 1st decimal. So in string I don't have `.12` but its still `Matches`.

What mistake i am making here.

```
import re

str = "100.13.1"
##if(re.match("^100\.[6|7|8|9|10|11|12]", str)):
if(re.search("^100\.[6|7|8|9|10|11|12]", str)):
 print("[Quit], Matches")
else:
 print("[info], Not match")
```

Comment: Can you provide a range of acceptable and unacceptable inputs? Your prose is a bit obscure.

Comment: Brackets `[]` are for character sets.  `[6|7|8|9|10|11|12]` boils down to characters `0126889|`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
import re

patt = r'100\.(6|7|8|9|10|11|12)'
data = '100.13.1'

if re.match(patt, data):
    print('[Quit], Matches')
else:
    print('[info], Not match')
```

Alternatively, this pattern will match numbers from `6` through `12`:

```
r'100\.([6-9]|1[0-2])'
```

Comment: `if(re.match(r'10\.(6|7|8|9|10|11|12)', str)):`
I was missing `r`